# KeychainItemWrapper returning NSZeroData?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, keychain

I am storing passwords on keychain using Apple's `KeychainItemWrapper`. At some point, if I try to fetch a password that was not setup yet using

```
  KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier accessGroup:nil];
  NSString *password = [keychain objectForKey:kSecValueData];
```

password returns with this identification on the debugger

```
password = (_NSZeroData *) class name = _NSZeroData
```

If I let the code go on and try to use this value it will crash.

This value is not a nil. If I test using `if (!password)` it will fail... and is not a string empty value (it will crash if I try to test it as a NSString).

How do I test this thing to see if it is valid before proceeding?

Comment: i had this same issue working fine after change kSecValueData to kSecAttrService

Comment: @SunnyShah - I discovered the problem and a solution for that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the problem and by the way, I hate with passion the crappy documentation Apple writes about everything.

This is the problem. Despite the documentation suggesting that you should store passwords like plain strings like this using `kSecValueData`:

```
  NSString *myPassword = @"12345";
  KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier accessGroup:nil];
  [keychain setObject:myPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

you should never do that. In fact `kSecValueData`, as the name suggests and the documentation should say, expects a `NSData` object. So, you must convert the `NSString` to NSData before storing it, like this:

```
  NSString *myPassword = @"12345";
  KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier accessGroup:nil];
  NSData *myPasswordData = [myPassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [keychain setObject:myPasswordData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

when getting it back you must cast it to `NSData` and convert it back to `NSString`:

```
  NSData *myPasswordData = (NSData *)[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

  NSString *myPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: myPasswordData
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```